# For how long open graph link should be accessible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We're sharing data on facebook using open graph meta tags. After initial crawl for how long link with the document should stay valid? Is it just stored in open graph and if the content do not change I don't need to care about it anymore? I couldn't find information about it in open graph documentation but it was probably me being lousy in looking for it

Comment: Facebook will automatically re-scrape Open Graph objects after a while – although that might only be the case if they are “used” again (f.e. someone tries to share them again). Original posts should not get changed (unless the user explicitly requests them to be updated) – but say, I see a post a friend of mine made a while ago, and re-share that post – then that might give unexpected results if the URL is not valid any more. So I’d say, if possible, simply keep them available – shouldn’t “cost” you too much, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said, Facebook will re-scrape an Open Graph objects (i.e. an URL) if any action is taken on it (share, like, etc.) and the last scrape for that object is more than 7 days old.

If the Facebook crawler returns an error in one of those re-scrapes (for instance, because the URL is not longer available) the action over that object will fail.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Would be nice if you would also clarify what will be the result of failed `action over that object`?